# Bluetooth reconnected broadcastreceiver Android

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I made an app that saves your position when the car bluetooth is turned off, like a parking reminder.

The problem is that sometimes the car bluetooth is switched off for a few seconds and reconnect during travel and the app store position by mistake.

I made a broadcast receiver that detects when the mobile bluetooth is disconnected from a device and start a service to save the location.

I wonder if there is any way , once the broadcast starts, check if the bluetooth has become reconnected to the device automatically or not.

Thanks!!

PD: Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I use a similar system with bluetooth LE dongle, and to avoid the accidental few seconds random disconnection I made a timer... When the bluetooth is disconnected for more than 5 seconds (or whatever time you estimate the best bet), then I consider it is really disconnected, otherwise if the bluetooth comes back during the timer, I just reset it and do not trigger the actions...

Comment: I try to do that in the BroadcastReceiver. I have a handler.postDelayed of 10 seconds in which I check the getstate ( ) of bluetoothadapter but always gives me STATE_ON when the state if the bt is reconnect should be STATE_CONNECTED.... 

thanks for answering

Comment: Maybe with watching for another broadcast, like ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED - or any other more useful - then from there try to make your own deductions, more accurately ?